# Generate a json object using column names as keys

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is it possible to generate a json object using the column name as keys automatically?
I have a table with many columns and I need to dump it into a json object.
I know I can do this using the JSON_OBJECT function but I was looking for a more condensed syntax that would allow me to do this without having to specify the name of all the columns

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT("col_a", m.col_a, "col_b", m.col_b, "col_c", m.col_c, ...)
  FROM largetable AS m
```

Something like this?

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(m.*)
  FROM largetable AS m
```

I'm using MariaDB version 10.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Json objects make sense in other languages ​​like javascript, C#... There are many libraries to convert the result of a MariaDB query into a list of json objects in most languages.
Also, a good practice is to make the database engine do as little effort as possible when performing queries and processing the result in the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course not possible, since the parser would not accept an odd number of parameters for the JSON_OBJECT function.

To do that in pure SQL, you can't do that within a single statement, since you need to retrieve the column names from information_schema first:

```
select @statement:=concat("SELECT JSON_OBJECT(", group_concat(concat("\"",column_name,"\"", ",", column_name)),") FROM mytable") from information_schema.columns where table_name="mytable" and table_schema="test";

prepare my_statement from statement;

execute my;
```

Much easier and faster is to convert the result in your application, for example in Python:

```
import mariadb, json

conn= mariadb.connect(db="test")
cursor= conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute("select * from mytable")
json_row= json.dumps(cursor.fetchone())
```